# Seeing the Big Bang

Tags: space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

The Big Bang happened almost 14 Billion years ago.
Theoretically speaking , if we could teleport (Instant teleportation) to somewhere that’s 20 Billion light years away from the Earth , if we looked at the Earth using a super telescope, what would we see?Would we see the Big Bang ? Would we see what there was before the Big Bang? Does such a place even exist? If no , would that mean the space is finite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: Hi Borna. See the question I've linked. The Big Bang wasn't an explosion that happened at a point and spread outwards from that point. The Big Bang happened everywhere at the same time.

Comment: @JohnRennie Oh. Wow, that's weird. Every single official description of the Big Bang tells us that everything DID begin at a tiny point before expanding rapidly. A literal tiny, incredibly dense point. Are they all wrong, and you alone correct?

Comment: @WhitePrime everyone who knows general relativity will say the same about the Big Bang. I am most certainly not alone in describing it this way. The trouble is that a giant explosion looks much more dramatic and the makers of TV programmes can rarely resist the temptation to put spectacle over substance.

Comment: You need to be careful about measuring distance in the expanding space. The objects, from which light has traveled to us 13 billion years, are not 13 billion light years away now, but much further, because space has expanded greatly over this time. In the current cosmological model, the observable universe has a limited size. If you teleport beyond this distance, from there you would not see the place where the Earth is now located. It would be hidden from you by the cosmic horizon.

Answer (score 1):

We would see something very similar to what we see on Earth, because the universe is very large (if not infinite), homogeneous and isotropic. You'd see cosmic background radiation from about 380,000y. You'd see highly redshifted young galaxies.

Note that the furthest we can see, with a look-back time of about 13.7 billion lightyears (the time it photons have been in flight from there) are about 46 billion lightyears away, because the universe expanded while those photons were in flight. Still, if you teleported there (or traveled through a wormhole), you'd still see a universe that looked very similar to how it looks from Earth.